# Render chrome extension popup UI dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension with a UI that is fetched from a remote server rather than having a static file in the extensions repository. I tried the following but chrome is not able to load the page.

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
    "popup": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/web.html"
});
```

I also added the domain in the list of permissions.
Is this requirement possible through google chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can't provide a remote page as a popup.

However, you can embed a remote page in your popup as an iframe (provided the remote page has no protection against being embedded).

Comment: The iframe solution looks good. But is it possible that my background page loads the layout using XHR and then send it to popup.html and rewrite the layout using document.write or whatever is the right object for poup?

Comment: On one hand, it's possible. On the other, that's a very bad idea from a security perspective (you're placing remote code into a much higher privilege context) and likely to break the page [due to CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). In fact, this idea is _so_ bad from the security perspective that it would probably cause your extension to be rejected in publishing if caught in review.

Comment: The best of both worlds would be to request (or scrape) data from the webpage, sanitize it, and render your own dynamic UI based on that.

Comment: Yes I had a slight hunch regarding the security issue of this approach

Comment: FYI the web page is under my control only. Could you tell me more on the rendering part? You mean to say use the document.write within the popup page to rewrite the layout

Comment: The page is under your control, but is it, and all resources, served only over HTTPS on endpoints you control? If not, such rewriting is going to break if there is any JS included.

Comment: The reason why I want this requirement is because, this way I have control over the extension updates. If I place a static html page and tomorrow I need to add/remove feature from the extension, the only possible way for this would be if the user updates the extension. Also this leads to maintaining backward compatibility with older version of the extension

Comment: Funny thing: Mozilla expressly forbids circumventing the update mechanism and Google frowns heavily upon it. When you need to update your extension, you should go through the update process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128156/discussion-between-xan-and-faiz-halde).